# In h5py, do I need to call flush() before I close a file?

Tags: python, h5py

In the Python HDF5 library `h5py`, do I need to `flush()` a file before I `close()` it?

Or does closing the file already make sure that any data that might still be in the buffers will be written to disk?

What exactly is the point of flushing? When would flushing be necessary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you do not need to flush the file before closing. Flushing is done automatically by the underlying HDF5 C library when you close the file.

---

As to the point of flushing. File I/O is slow compared to things like memory or cache access. If programs had to wait before data was *actually on the disk* each time a write was performed, that would slow things down a lot. So the actual writing to disk is buffered by at least the OS, but in many cases by the I/O library being used (e.g., the C standard I/O library). When you ask to write data to a file, it usually just means that the OS has copied your data to its own internal buffer, and will actually put it on the disk when it's convenient to do so.

Flushing overrides this buffering, at whatever level the call is made. So calling `h5py.File.flush()` will flush the HDF5 library buffers, but not necessarily the OS buffers. The point of this is to give the program some control over when data actually leaves a buffer.

For example, writing to the standard output is usually line-buffered. But if you really want to see the output before a newline, you can call `fflush(stdout)`. This might make sense if you are piping the standard output of one process into another: that downstream process can start consuming the input right away, without waiting for the OS to decide it's a good time.

Another good example is making a call to `fork(2)`. This usually copies the entire address space of a process, which means the I/O buffers as well. That may result in duplicated output, unnecessary copying, etc. Flushing a stream guarantees that the buffer is empty before forking.

Comment: Could I run into problems if writing to network folders via a NFS share?